# git remote is not shown using altered git command sequence

Tags: git

I have two remotes, 'origin' and 'hal' to manage.

Branches 'origin/mine' and 'hal/their' are meant to a "mirror" of each other.

'origin' are there for daily access while 'hal' are there for monthly releases.

If I clone 'hal' ... and pull 'origin/mine', I can see 'hal' in 'gitg branch -a' or 'gitg'.

However, if I clone 'origin'... and pull 'hal/their', 'hal' is not shown as the log shown below.

```
me@int_svr:/home/me/work$ cd boot/; git branch -a
* mine
  remotes/m/master -> origin/mine
  remotes/origin/mine

me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = repoman@int_git:repo/boot
        projectname = boot
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "mine"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/mine
[remote "hal"]
        url = ssh://out_src@hal/home/out_src/boot
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/hal/*

me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ git checkout -b their
me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ git pull hal their
From ssh://hal/home/out_src/boot
 * branch            their -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ git config branch.their.remote hal
me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ git config branch.their.merge refs/heads/their

me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ git branch -a
* mine
  remotes/m/master -> origin/mine
  remotes/origin/mine

me@int_svr:/home/me/work/boot$ cat .git/config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = repoman@int_git:repo/boot
        projectname = boot
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "mine"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/mine
[remote "hal"]
        url = ssh://out_src@hal/home/out_src/boot
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/hal/*
[branch "their"]
        remote = hal
        merge = refs/heads/their
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure, try:

```
git fetch hal
git branch -avv
```

Comment: 'git fetch hal' is known OK.
I prefer 'git fetch hal <Specific branch>' that can't make hal shown however.